# react-native Text Input overflow text

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, textinput

I am developing a react-native app with multi-line TextInput fields.

The TextInputs are used as inputs but also to display the content, in display mode the TextInput is disabled (`editable={false}`).

I would like to let the user filling the form to overflow if needed and the user that reads the input (display mode) to be able to see the over-flowing text. I thought of using the scroll option but there are two problems with it:

1. It is also disabled when the TextInput is disabled
2. The request is to overflow the text because the form will eventually be printed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I applied was to create a `<Text />` component and pass the input value there. Because in react-native `<Text />` adjusts it's height to the height of the string it displays.